# I can't get the red rectangle in the top center of my splashscreen

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new in android development.
I tried to create my first Splashscreen with a red rectangle in the top center and a purple background like the first image:
[image: Wanted Splashscreen]

But I got it like this as a result of my code:

[image: My work]

This is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:paddingTop="0dp" android:paddingEnd="0dp" android:paddingStart="0dp">

Background_splash.xml:
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:paddingTop="0dp" android:paddingEnd="0dp" android:paddingStart="0dp">

    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="fill_horizontal|fill_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/purple_rectangle"
            />
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/red_rectangle"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

So can you help me to correct my code and add the red rectangle in the top and smaller like the first image.
Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#3949AB">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="#F80000"
        android:layout_margin="50dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is easy with linear layouts

Comment: thanks kelvin but I can't use LinearLayout in my xml file in android studio it gives me an error that I should define it

Comment: Copy paste this in your activity's xml file

Answer (score 1):

put your shape in a RelativeLayout. then add this attribute for your

```
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
 android:android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
```